# How to insert an array of strings in javascript into PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am building an API server which accepts file uploads using multer.

I need to store an array of all the paths to all files uploaded for each request to a column in the PostgreSQL database which I have connected to the server.

Say I have a table created with the following query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS records
  (
   id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   created_on TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
   created_by INTEGER,
   title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   type  VARCHAR NOT NULL
  )
```

How do I define a new column `filepaths` on the above table where I can insert a javascript string array (ex: `['path-to-file-1', 'path-to-file-2', 'path-to-file-3']`).

Also how do I retrive, update/edit the list in javascript using `node-postgres`

Comment: You have example codes for `node-postgres` in their documentation on their [site](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries). If you plan to have multiple queries frequently, then you need [pooling](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. use `json` or `jsonb` type. In the case string to insert will look:

   ```
   '["path-to-file-1", "path-to-file-2", "path-to-file-3"]'
   ```

   I would prefer `jsonb` - it allows to have good indexes. Json is rather just text with some additional built-in functions.
2. Use array of text - something like `filepaths text[]`. To insert you can use:

   ```
   ARRAY ['path-to-file-1', 'path-to-file-2', 'path-to-file-3']
   ```

   or

   ```
   '{path-to-file-1,path-to-file-2,path-to-file-3,"path to file 4"}'
   ```

   You need to use " here only for elements that contain space and so on. But you fill free to use it for all elements too.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `file` table that has a path column and a foreign key reference to the record that it belongs to. This way you can store the path as just a text column instead of storing an array in a column, which is better practice for relational databases. You'll also be able to store additional information on a file if you need to later. And it'll be more simple to interact with the file path records since you'd add a new file path by just inserting a new row into the `file` table (with the appropriate foreign key) and remove by deleting a row from the `file` table.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS file (
    record_id   integer NOT NULL REFERENCES records(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    path        text NOT NULL
);
```

Then to get all the files for a record you can join the two tables together and convert to an array if you want.

For example:

```
SELECT
    records.*,
    ARRAY (
        SELECT
            file.path
        FROM
            file
        WHERE
            records.id = file.record_id
    ) AS file_paths
FROM
    records;
```

Sample input (using only the title field of records):

```
INSERT INTO records (title) VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C');
INSERT INTO file (record_id, path) VALUES (1, 'patha1'), (1, 'patha2'), (1, 'patha3'), (2, 'pathb1');
```

Sample output:

```
 id | title |       file_paths       
----+-------+------------------------
  1 | A     | {patha1,patha2,patha3}
  2 | B     | {pathb1}
  3 | C     | {}
```